# AnimatePresence and motion.div not working when using in ternary operator

Tags: animation, framer-motion

I am learning `framer-motion` so that I can add nice animations in to my application.

I am rendering a `YES/NO` value based on `disclosure` visibility and wanted to have `fade-in/fade-out` animation whenever `YES/NO` options gets `rendered/exit`.

Below is the code which I am using

```
<AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
  {
    disclosure.visible ? (
      <motion.div
        initial={{ opacity: 0, duration: 2 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1, duration: 2 }}
        exit={{ opacity: 0, duration: 2, delay: 1 }}
      >
        <div>YES</div>
      </motion.div>
    ) : (
      <motion.div
        initial={{ opacity: 0, duration: 2 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1, duration: 2 }}
        exit={{ opacity: 0, duration: 2, delay: 1 }}
      >
        <div>NO</div>
      </motion.div>
    )
  }
</AnimatePresence>
```

Can anybody please help me?
Please let me know if I am missing something.

***** UPDATE *****

If I just use code below then animation work for `YES` option

```
<AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
  <motion.div
    initial={{ opacity: 0, duration: 2 }}
    animate={{ opacity: 1, duration: 2 }}
    exit={{ opacity: 0, duration: 2, delay: 1 }}
  >
    <div>YES</div>
  </motion.div>  
</AnimatePresence>
```

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to resolve this issue by adding `key="expanded"` in first `motion.div` and `key="collapsed"` attribute in second `motion.div`.

Comment: nice! yeah, that will get you. Adding the explicit key is a pain point of the docs I think

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add same key to both `div` element which is the key is the thing that trigger the animation. So, when the key is changing framer-motion will trigger the animation. Don't forget to add `exitBeforeEnter` attribute in `AnimatePresance` tag. This attribute has function to make sure another `div` is not rendered when `div` element that in exit phase still in process. Here is some example:

```
<AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
    {isLoading ? (
        <motion.div
            key={`${isLoading}`}
            initial="initial"
            animate="animate"
            exit="exit"
            variants={aLoadingAnimation}
        >
            ...
        </motion.div>
    ) : (
        <motion.div
            key={`${isLoading}`}
            initial="initial"
            animate="animate"
            exit="exit"
            variants={aLoadingAnimation}
        >
            ...
        </motion.div>
    )}
</AnimatePresence>
```

and `animation.ts` is contain this code

```
export const aLoadingAnimation = {
    initial: {
        opacity: 0,
    },
    animate: {
        opacity: 1,
    },
    exit: {
        opacity: 0,
        transition: {
            duration: 3,
        },
    },
}
```

If you notice there is transition object in exit object which contain duration with 3 value. I added duration key to make sure `exitBeforeEnter` is working properly. Because when I added duration key I can see the element animation slowly.

I hope this help, it works on me.

Comment: Ran into the same problem. Setting the key attribute worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a unique `id` attribute to each `motion.div`, this will help the `AnimatePresence` to track the elements.

Ex:

```
<AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
  {
    disclosure.visible ? (
      <motion.div
        initial={{ opacity: 0, duration: 2 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1, duration: 2 }}
        exit={{ opacity: 0, duration: 2, delay: 1 }}
        id="motionYes"
      >
        <div>YES</div>
      </motion.div>
    ) : (
      <motion.div
        initial={{ opacity: 0, duration: 2 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1, duration: 2 }}
        exit={{ opacity: 0, duration: 2, delay: 1 }}
        id="motionNo"
      >
        <div>NO</div>
      </motion.div>
    )
  }
</AnimatePresence>
```

Check this: https://stephenweiss.dev/react-key-props-and-why-you-shouldnt-be-using-index